# Is there a way to dynamically create tables without knowing how many columns the table will have beforehand?

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql, dynamic-columns, dynamic-tables

The following query uses a pivot to turn the values in field [expireDate Year-Month] into column headings. Because the number of year-months regularly increases and is not fixed, this is done dynamically.Is there a way to also dynamically create a table from the output without knowing how many columns the table will have beforehand?

```
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([expireDate Year-Month])

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  [expireDate Year-Month] FROM REPORTING_DATA.tableau.vw_vehicleInspDetailsHistMonthlyFinal) AS PivotExample

SELECT   @PivotColumns

--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT DISTINCT Vehicle#, ' +   @PivotColumns + '

    FROM REPORTING_DATA.tableau.vw_vehicleInspDetailsHistMonthlyFinal 

    PIVOT( MAX(inspectionResult)
          FOR [expireDate Year-Month] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) 
     AS P
     ORDER BY Vehicle#  '

SELECT   @SQLQuery
--Execute dynamic query

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Comment: Is [`select ... into`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) what you are looking for?

Comment: @HABO - How would I use "SELECT...INTO" in conjunction with the query about? If you stick it in the code being assigned to the **SQLquery** variable, the temp table disappears as soon as **EXEC** runs so you can't do anything with it.

Comment: Where did the requirement for a temporary table come into this? A global [temporary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables), where the name starts with `##`, or a plain olde table should persist after the dynamic SQL executes.